# How to load module only in linux?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Here is my try:

```
(if (eq system-type 'gnu/linux)
    (load "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/site-gentoo")
    (require 'site-gentoo))
```

But anyways I receive error on windows :

```
/.emacs':

File error: Cannot open load file, site-gentoo
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is in the way you use `if`: its documentation says it's

```
(if COND THEN ELSE...)
```

I.e. your `(require 'site-gentoo)` gets executed if and only if it's **not** a GNU/Linux system.

Use `when` instead, that should do what you intend.

Also, there should actually no need to use both `load` and `require`, their usage should have the same result. The differences are mostly that `require` will search the `load-path` and don't load something again that was already loaded before.

Answer (score 4):

It should be:

```
(if (eq system-type 'gnu/linux)
    (progn
      (load "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/site-gentoo")
      (require 'site-gentoo)))
```

or

```
(when (eq system-type 'gnu/linux)
    (load "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/site-gentoo")
    (require 'site-gentoo))
```

Instead of `(load "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/site-gentoo")` you should add the folder containing the load file to the `load-path`:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/")
```

That should do the trick. `require` only works for files on the `load-path`, `load` on the other hand simply evaluates the lisp file it was given as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Rörd and Bozhidar Batsov have already provided the answer as to how to resolve it, but just to add in the reason why your original code was failing.

`(if COND THEN ELSE...)` only accepts a single `THEN` command.  To be able to have it evaluate multiple commands when it returns true you have to wrap the commands in `(progn BODY...)`.

Your code was stating:
If on linux:     `(load "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/site-gentoo")`
If not on linux: `(require 'site-gentoo)`

Using `(when ...)` or wrapping in `(progn ...)` will both provide the desired solution.